# Can I expense a purchase of a used computer?

Tags: taxes, expenses

I'm freelancing on the side individually, and I want to buy a used computer for it off of Craigslist. Can I write this off as an expense and how would I get a receipt for it?

I'm in the U.S.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is far too vague. I'm going to assume you're living in the US and operating under U.S. tax law and your question about "writing it off" is in reference to your federal taxes.

You can either write the purchase value off as a business expense, or write off depreciation over several years. If you use the computer for any purposes other than work, you should log how many hours a day you spend working on the computer vs personal time, and deduct a corresponding percentage. For example, if 50% of the time spent using that computer is for business purposes and 50% for personal purposes, you can only deduct 50% of the cost. See https://turbotax.intuit.com/tax-tools/tax-tips/Tax-Deductions-and-Credits/Mobile-Phones--Internet-and-Other-Easy-Tax-Deductions/INF17751.html

> how would I get a receipt for it?

Ask for a receipt.